# 409 error when using streaming_bulk() - certain that document is only included once.

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am attempting to upload a large number of documents - about 7 million.

I have created actions for each document to be added and split them up into about 260 files, about 30K documents each.

Here is the format of the actions:

```
a = someDocument with nesting

esActionFromFile = [{
'_index': 'mt-interval-test-9', 
'_type': 'doc', 
'_id': 5641254, 
'_source': a, 
'_op_type': 'create'}]
```

I have tried using helpers.bulk, helpers.parallel_bulk, and helpers.streaming_bulk and have had partial success using helpers.bulk and helpers.streaming_bulk.

Each time I run a test, I delete, and then recreate the index using:

```
# Refresh Index
es.indices.delete(index=index, ignore=[400, 404])
es.indices.create(index = index, body = mappings_request_body)
```

When I am partially successful - many documents are loaded, but eventually I get a 409 version conflict error.

I am aware that there can be version conflicts created when there has not been sufficient time for ES to process the deletion of individual documents after doing a delete by query.

At first, I thought that something similar was happening here. However, I realized that I am often **getting the errors from files the first time they have ever been processed** (i.e. even if the deletion was causing issues, this particular file had never been loaded, so there couldn't be a conflict).

The **_id value I am using is the primary key from the original database** where I am extracting the data from - so **I am certain they are unique**. Furthermore, I have checked whether there was unintentional duplication of records in my actions arrays, or the files I created them from, and **there are no duplicates**.

I am at a loss to explain why this is happening, and struggling to find a solution to upload my data.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There should be information attached to the `409` response that should tell you exactly what's going wrong and which document caused it.

Another thing that could cause this would be a `retry` - when `elasticsearch-py` cannot connect to the cluster it will resend the request again to a different node. In some complex scenarios it can happen that a request will be thus sent twice. This is especially true if you enabled `retry_on_timeout` option.

Comment: Always appreciate your responses to these questions - thank you.

The extra details I get from the 409 response tell me that this is a versioning error - it's telling me that "document already exists (current version [1]). 

I have not explicitly tried to set or differentiate between different versions of these documents - this is the first time they are all being loaded. 

I did actually notice that I was getting many "time out" errors when trying to use parallel_bulk and I wasn't able to determine why. 

How might I troubleshoot this? 

I'm using Compose ES on IBM if that matters!

Comment: `bulk` api can be quite heavy, if you are getting timeouts it is likely that your cluster is just not fast enough to ingest at that speed. The solution is to slow down by either sending smaller batches or increasing the timeout. To see what is happening inside the cluster have a look at `/_cat/thread_pools/bulk?v` - it will show you busy threads and waiting requests. From what you describe it looks like some documents were loaded 2x, you can change `_op_type` to `index` to ignore safely or debug.

Comment: Thanks Honza - two questions for you:
1. I am using ES on Compose from the IBM cloud - I don't think I can access the cluster directly...based on your experience with that service, do you think it could be a hardware issue?

2. I thought that "create" would ignore duplicate records, while index would not? Will try to find the reference in the docs I am thinking of.

Comment: 1. I have no experience with IBM cloud unfortunately.

Comment: 2. `index` will index "over" an existing document if there are duplicate IDs, overwriting it whereas `create` will throw an error.

Comment: Hey Honza -  I had an idea about what the issue may be...

The documents that I am loading have 4 inner, nested documents. I have manually assigned an _id to the parent/highest level documents based on an important (and unique) value from the original database. 

The manually assigned _id's are 7 digit numbers. Is it possible that the nested documents, which have automatic id's assigned, are attempting to use an _id that I manually specified? 

I have tried to spot check a few instances of a conflict, but have not been able to verify what the automatically assigned child _id's look like

Comment: Nested documents don't have ids on the elasticsearch level so those won't cause any conflict.